# Why CellClick event does not fire when SelectionChanged event in DataGridView?

Tags: c#, datagridview

dataGridView1_SelectionChanged event fire when i select a row but dataGridView1_CellClick event is not firing. I am using one grid only.

```
private void mgInvoice_SelectionChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (this.IsFlagForShowImage)
            {
                ////If show image flag is true then only show images for invoices.
                try
                {
                    if (this.mgInvoice.SelectedRows != null)
                    {
                        if (this.mgInvoice.SelectedRows.Count > 0)
                        {
                            invoice = this.mgInvoice.SelectedRows[0].DataBoundItem as TAPInvoice;

                        Thread th = new Thread(new ThreadStart(LoadDocumentIdByInvoice));
                        th.Start();

                        this.ShowInvoiceImageDocumentByDocId(this.invoice);
                        IsModifiedCollection = true;

                        //Zahid
                        this.SetPriviliges();
                    }
                }
            }
            catch
            {
                throw;
            }
            finally
            {

            }
        }
    }
```

the above event fire correctly. but below mention event does not fire.

```
private void mgInvoice_CellClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
        {
            if (this.mgInvoice.Columns["FImagesReviewed"].Visible)
            {
                this.mgInvoice.Columns["FImagesReviewed"].Visible = true;

            }
        else if (this.mgInvoice.Columns["FImagesApproved"].Visible)
        {
            this.mgInvoice.Columns["FImagesApproved"].Visible = true;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Maybe because `SelectionChanged` event attached to `dgvApInvoice` and `CellClick` to `mgInvoice`? Not the same control? O its just nameing issue?

Comment: No this is a same grid

Comment: Double check designer file or via designer if event handles is really attached. Does not fire you mean does not hit breakpoint?

Comment: Why is your Try-Catch-Finally block laid out like that? I didn't even know you could separate them like that.

Comment: Can we see more code on how you attach these handlers?

Comment: Can you try suspending/removing mgInvoice_SelectionChanged event and only checking cell click event? I had once case, where an event was taking longer time, which caused second event to never be fired somehow.

Comment: Yes, you should try removing SelectionChanged, leave CellClick attached, and see whether it fires now.  How are you wiring up the event handlers?

Comment: This may be old but this still happens. To show the bug, place a break point in the selectionchanged event and one in the cellclick event. When the selectionchanged break point is hit continue walking through the code and you will see that the cellclick event does not fire. Remove the selectionchanged breakpoint and try again. The cellclick event will fire. Anyone know why?

Comment: I can confirm it still happens. I am using VS2017, though a bit older now, got here because it happens exactly as @Tom lays it out. Still no answer I guess. I will see if I can create a work-around.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. There was an assignment to the CurrentCell of the DataGridView in the SelectionChanged event handler:

```
_DataGridView.CurrentCell = cellToSelect;
```

After I removed this assignment the CellClick event was fired again.

Answer (score 0):

So it seems that as long as the SelectionChanged event fires, the CellContentClick event is "ignored". As long as the SelectionChanged does not fire (the row has already been selected), the CellContentClick event will fire. This would preclude when the user clicks the cell of an unselected row. I tried using different selection methods, but none changed this behavior. Not sure why this would be as designed rather than a bug, but it seems it has been this way (obviously) for a long time. The only workaround I could come up with seems kludgy at best, but at least it works. In the first line of the SelectionChanged event, I used the CurrentCell property to determine which cell was clicked and call my own CellContentClick event, passing the row index and the column index from the CurrentCell property. Example code below. I added the reference within the Windows CellContentClick event to handle when the row was selected before the cell was clicked.

```
private void MyDataGridView_SelectionChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // SelectionChanged code to run before CellContentClick event code
    var cc = MyDataGridView.CurrentCell;
    MyDataGridView_MyCellContentClickEvent(cc.ColumnIndex, cc.RowIndex);
    // SelectionChanged code to run after CellContentClick event
}

private void MyDataGridView_MyCellContentClickEvent(int ColumnIndexIn, int RowIndexIn)
{
    // Execute your CellContentClick code here
}

private void MyDataGridView_CellContentClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    MyDataGridView_MyCellContentClickEvent(e.ColumnIndex, e.RowIndex);
}
```